# DataGrid not sizing correctly

Tags: wpf, datagrid

As you can see, I have two [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189753.aspx)s in my app. For reasons unknown, one or both of the grids will not be correctly sized when the application starts. (The images are loaded programmatically.)

Does anyone know why and, more importantly, a way to fix this issue?

An odd thing to note is that the grid resizes itself when the mouse scroll button is scrolled over it, but the scroll button does not scroll the grid (only page up/down and cursor keys do, except, of course, dragging the scrollbar). Also, even if the `ScrollViewer` is removed, the problem persists.

[image: images in a datagrid that is incorrectly sized]

### XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="SW.ImagesControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:SW="clr-namespace:SW">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <SW:NullImageConverter x:Key="NullImageConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Padding="0" Margin="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="Cell"
             VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">
                  <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                      <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Name="tb" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">Browse...</Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource NullImageConverter}}" Margin="0"/>
                      </Grid>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="img" Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}">
                          <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                  </Button.Template>
                </Button>
              </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Preview">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding PreviewImage, Converter={StaticResource NullImageConverter}}" Margin="0" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</UserControl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` has an internal `ScrollViewer`, so the external one is unnecessary. This might not have been obvious, though, because `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` was set to `Recycling`. Removing that attribute and the scrollviewer solves the sizing issue as well as the lack of scrolling.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SW.ImagesControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:SW="clr-namespace:SW">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <SW:NullImageConverter x:Key="NullImageConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Padding="0" Margin="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">
              <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Name="tb" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">Browse...</Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource NullImageConverter}}" Margin="0"/>
                  </Grid>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="img" Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}">
                      <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                      <!--<Setter TargetName="img" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>-->
                    </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Button.Template>
            </Button>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Preview">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding PreviewImage, Converter={StaticResource NullImageConverter}}" Margin="0" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</UserControl
```